# problems with the update of a label Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, button, tkinter, label

I'm really stuck on a basilary things: I have this code

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

import subprocess

import tkinter as tk

def cd():  
    f=(subprocess.check_output("net view"))
    e=(f.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
    label1=Label(text=e).pack()


def mainscreen(): 
    mainscreen=Tk()
    mainscreen.title("Terfysgol's kit V 2.0")
    frame1=Frame(mainscreen)
    frame1.pack()
    puls1=Button(frame1,text="List of device", borderwidth= "2",command= cd).pack()

mainscreen()
```

When I run it all the time that I press the button it create a new label but I only want to update the text of the label1.

Comment: 1. Don't chain your geometry methods. You did it correctly with `frame1`, but incorrectly with `label1` and `puls1`. 2. Every time you press the button, it creates a new label, because you told it to. Create the label first, in `mainscreen()`, and then have `cd()` simply update it with `label1.config(text=e)`.

Comment: uhm now i have the following situation: in mainscreen() i have  label1= Label(mainscreen).pack but when i press puls1 it gives me an erro that says that in cd() label1 is not defined.

Comment: Then create `label1` somewhere safe from garbage collection (outside a function). And again, don't chain the geometry methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are after:

```
def cd():

    f=(subprocess.check_output("net view"))
    e=(f.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
    label1.config(text = e)
```

and then at the top of your program after your imports you need to put:

```
label1 = Label()
label1.pack()
```

Please note that I'm not suggesting this is good program structure, but that is up to you to sort out. This answer is just a quick fix to provide you with enough information to work out the rest of what you need.

Also you can remove the `import tkinter as tk` line already imports tkinter.